# How to add parameters to run SBT in Ammonite?

Tags: scala, sbt, ammonite

I want to run this `SBT` command in Ammonite:

```
sbt -mem 3000 clean compile docker:publishLocal
```

I tried a few things like:

```
%.sbt("-mem 3000", 'clean, 'test)(pwd)
```

Which gives this exception:

```
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Not a valid command: -
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected 'addPluginSbtFile'
[error] -mem 3000
[error]  ^
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to the same thing, and i can tell you that is not fun when those "random" errors happen.

```
// I had to put the full path where sbt is, like this
val SBT = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\bin\\sbt.bat"

%(SBT, "-mem", "3000", "clean", "compile", "docker:publishLocal")(pwd)
```

with this the solution is:

```
%.sbt("-mem", "3000", 'clean, 'test)(pwd)
```

Comment: thanks - with your answer - this works: `%.sbt("-mem", "3000", 'clean, 'test)(pwd)`.  If you add this to your answer I can accept it;).